# Pagination with Elastic Search in Titan

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I am using Elastic Search with Titan. How can I do pagination in ES with titan?

I saw [THIS](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) and so was trying this:

```
Iterable<Result<Vertex>> vertices = g.indexQuery("search","v.testTitle:(mytext)")
            .addParameter(new Parameter("from", 0))
            .addParameter(new Parameter("size", 2)).vertices();    

for (Result<Vertex> result : vertices) {
    Vertex tv = result.getElement();
    System.out.println(tv.getProperty("testTitle")+ ": " + result.getScore());
}
```

The thing is it return all 4-5 records not in the size of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters are not yet supported. The method only exists for future implementations.
However, you can currently limit your result. The following code should work:

```
Iterable<Result<Vertex>> vertices = g.indexQuery("search","v.testTitle:(mytext)")
            .limit(2).vertices();    

for (Result<Vertex> result : vertices) {
    Vertex tv = result.getElement();
    System.out.println(tv.getProperty("testTitle")+ ": " + result.getScore());
}
```

...but you can't specify an offset.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: but this is not a pagination. Imagine a web page where I am displaying the search result 10 record per page . how will i get NEXT and PREVIOUS record?

Comment: As I've said, that's currently not supported. You'll have to find a workaround or implement it yourself and send a pull request.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I execute the same query directly from ES java client.I was following http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/0.90/search.html#search this code but it was fetching 0 records. May be I am setting or missing wrong parameter. I did `client.prepareSearch("titan")` `.setQuery(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("offerTitle", "mytext"))` its returning 0 hits

Answer (score 0):

I don know anyrthing about titan.But for implementing pagination concept in Elasticsearch ,you can use scroll concept.It will help a lot and Its like db cursor.. it reduces CPU usage a lot.

Refer http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html